# Open Yes / No Notification Box from UI thread in a Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to prompt the user with a yes/no dialog in my WP app. The problem is that I'm already in the UI thread, so either I won't be able to get the result before continuing or I'm running into an infinite loop (since the box cannot open while I'm blocking the UI thread).

```
bool result = false;
bool done = false;
NotificationTool.Show(title, text,
  new NotificationAction("Yes", () => { result = true; done = true; }),
  new NotificationAction("No", () => { result = false; done = true; }));
while (!done)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
return result;
```

Is there a way to wait for the result without "blocking" the UI thread?

Comment: Why were my edits reverted? They contained valid and (in my opinion) relevant information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox` and then `EndShowMessageBox` methods from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll assembly. The API allows you to show a message boxes with 1 or 2 arbitrary labeled buttons.

Comment: Wow, that does exactly what I need. For others who stumble it, this is the code I used: `IAsyncResult result = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(title, text, new string[] { "yes", "no" }, 0, new MessageBoxIcon(), null, null);
return Guide.EndShowMessageBox(result) == 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Async/await programming concept in Windows Phone. This allows you to invoke a UI thread when the dialog box receives the response from the user.

Check the Async/Await programming concepts in below link.

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8

Please mark as answer if my post helps you to resolve your problem.

Thanks,
Kamal.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. I would have to mess up my encapsulation for this. I'm rather looking for a solution similar to the built-in 'MessageBox.Show' which can be used from the UI thread without any async code. But unfortunately, it only supports "ok" and "cancel" buttons.